# Errors when running a very old XSLT stylesheet in more modern browsers

Tags: xml, xslt

I got some xml code that was written about 10 years back and it still works fine in IE7. However, if I run it in latest versions of any internet browsers, I get an error. The error points that I should remove one of the xml tags, and also that ':' isn't supposed to be where it is (2nd row at the beginning). The error I get is:

> warning on line 2 at column 17: xmlParsePITarget: invalid name prefix 'xml' Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error....

I tried to remove the colon, but it doesn't help.  Any suggestions?

`web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml:stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="menus.xsl"?>
...
```

`menus.xsl`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE webmenu [
    <!ENTITY nbsp "&#xA0;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">
<!-- MENUS.XSL -->

<xsl:template match="/">
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE><xsl:value-of select="TOPICLIST/@TYPE" /></TITLE>
    <LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="menus.css" />
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JScript" SRC="menus.js"></SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <IMG src="a_top.jpg"/>


    <!-- BUILD MENUBAR -->

    <DIV ID="divMenuBar">
    <TABLE ID="tblMenuBar" BORDER="0">
    <TR>
    <xsl:for-each select="//TOPICS[TOPIC]">
        <TD CLASS="clsMenuBarItem">
            <xsl:attribute name="ID">tdMenuBarItem<xsl:value-of select="@TYPE" /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="@TYPE" />
        </TD>
        <xsl:if test="context()[not(end())]">
        <TD>|</TD>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
    </DIV>

    <!-- BUILD INDIVIDUAL MENUS -->

    <xsl:for-each select="//TOPICS[TOPIC]">
        <DIV CLASS="clsMenu">
        <xsl:attribute name="ID">divMenu<xsl:value-of select="@TYPE" /></xsl:attribute>
            <DIV CLASS="clsMenuSpacer"></DIV>
            <xsl:for-each select="TOPIC">
            <DIV>
            <A CLASS="clsMenuItem">
                <xsl:attribute name="NAME"><xsl:value-of select="DESC"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="HREF"><xsl:value-of select="URL" /></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="TITLE" />
            </A>
            </DIV>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </DIV>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <!-- BOTTOM TREATMENTS -->
    <TABLE>
    <TR><TD height="220"></TD></TR>
    <TR><TD><TABLE align="bottom" width="520"><TR><TD height="100">
    <TEXTAREA ROWS="6" COLS="80" READONLY="yes" ID="txtDescription">
    </TEXTAREA></TD></TR><TR><TD>
    <!-- FAST SEARCH -->
    <form action="http://www.alltheweb.com/cgi-bin/search" method="GET" name="">
        <a href="http://www.fastsearch.com/"><img src="fastlogo80.gif" align="middle" alt="FAST Web Search" border="0"/></a>
        <FONT COLOR="#528294" FACE="verdana,helvetica,sans-serif" SIZE="-1"><B> Web Search</B></FONT>
        <input size="30" name="query"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form></TD></TR></TABLE>
    </TD><TD width="400" align="right"><IMG src="tagline.jpg"/></TD></TR>

    </TABLE>

    </BODY>
    </HTML>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "The error points out that..." - rather than paraphrasing the error, please [edit] the question to include the exact text of the error you receive.

Comment: Error message is as follows when I open web.xml:

"warning on line 2 at column 17: xmlParsePITarget: invalid name prefix 'xml'
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error...."

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to StackOverflow and I am learning how to use it properly.

Comment: @AmirHajdar in that case, welcome! Learning is good and you will find that this is quite different from normal forums. There's a [tour] you may find interesting :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> warning on line 2 at column 17: xmlParsePITarget: invalid name prefix 'xml' Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error...

Yes, the prefix XML is reserved. You are using it as a prefix in an NCName production for the processing instruction, which is not allowed in XML+Namespaces (it was allowed prior to namespaces introduction, but that was a very brief period and predates even IE4).

> ```
> <?xml:stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="menus.xsl"?>
> ```

That is what the browser is complaining about. Having this is disallowed in any XML file. In fact, any processing instruction with a colon is disallowed, it only allows NCName, not a QName.

The proper line you are looking for [is probably this](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/):

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="menus.xsl"?>
```

This will enable stylesheet processing of your XML in browsers that support it.

The fact that some browsers exist that silently ignore the error can be considered a blessing or a curse.

> I tried to remove the colon, but it doesn't help. Any suggestions?

I think after removing it you received a *different* error (hence it is so important to show the exact error(s)). Because removing it would still not leave the XML invalid, but the browser will not understand the processing instruction.

---

#### Update about your XSLT

You wrote:

> was written about 10 years back
>
> ```
> <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">
> ```

I missed this on a cursory read earlier. ***This is indeed not valid.*** It is part of a *never officially published version of XSLT prior to version 1.0*.

You can find it here, the [Working Draft of 1998](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/WD-xsl-19980818#AEN81):

> All XSL defined elements, that is those specified in this document with a prefix of xsl:, will only be recognized by the XSL processor if they belong to a namespace with the URI http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl; XSL defined elements are recognized only in the stylesheet not in the source document.

And for historical value, [below that](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/WD-xsl-19980818#issue-versioning):

> **Issue (versioning):** Should there be some way for a stylesheet to indicate which version of XSL it conforms to? Can this be done through the URI of the XSL namespace?

And long since then (since 1999), it *is required to have a version attribute and it is required to have the proper namespace*.

So, this makes your stylesheet possibly 18 years old. Because 17 years ago, the standard was published and the namespace required was then, and has been since:

```
http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform
```

Unfortunately, the wrong namespace made it into some book which sold pretty well, that was published before the final version came out, and people started using it.

Even more unfortunate, for years on, Microsoft kept using this wrong namespace, while also allowing the proper namespace. They have only fixed that half a decade ago or something. Hence your error.

My rant aside, just fix as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="1.0">
```

And finally, here is the *[mea culpa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mea_culpa)* from Microsoft, [mentioning that since Internet Explorer 9](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the legacy stylesheet namespace is no longer supported. Exactly the issue that hit you.

They also say (the first issue you faced):

> Processing instructions with the name xml:stylesheet (note the colon) no longer cause XSLT to be processed:

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help...I get the following error:  Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed.

Comment: @AmirHajdar, so it actually _did help_, at least in part ;). This means that your XML was loaded (a big plus!) and that now you have a different problem in the XSLT file. Please show (in your Q.) the offending parts, i.e., create a minimal version of that stylesheet until you have the offending lines and paste that, see also [mcve].

Comment: @AmirHajdar, I missed something in your original question, which causes the second error. Please see my update (2nd half of my answer). In fact, _the offending parts_ were already there, but I didn't see it.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I couldn't pin point the error as I'm learning XML as we speak.  I had to paste all the menus.xsl code...I hope that's not a problem.

Comment: Now I get the following error (after updating xsl file): "Error loading stylesheet: Invalid XSLT/XPath function."

Comment: @AmirHajdar Have a look at [oXygen](http://oxygenxml.com) or Visual Studio or any other XSLT editor, it will make your life much easier as they will simply underline the error and make suggestions. I did that (load your xslt) and found that you need to: change `context` to `current` and change `end` to `last`.

Comment: @AmirHajdar, and no, no problem at all, it is a very small stylesheet, easy enough for us to handle ;). If you want to learn about XML and XSLT, [this is an excellent introduction and foundations course](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/xslt-foundations-part1), worth your time and (a little) money. I know the person who made it, he was a co-creator of the XSLT specifications.

Comment: Ok, now, the page is being displayed in Firefox and Safari but menu is not working.  Chrome doesn't even render it all.

Comment: (I cannot find a free xslt editor yet for mac...the one people suggest doesn't work any more!)

Comment: @AmirHajdar Since you're new round here, I understand the temptation to keep adding comments until everything is working perfectly, like you would on a forum. But this site works a little differently, with the aim that each page contains one question and its answer. I'd say the original question has been answered very thoroughly now, and any further follow-ups need to be posted as new, self-contained, questions, with their own examples.

Comment: Ok, I will try to formulate a proper question.  @Abel, thank you for all your help, and I will try to explore the site you suggested.

Comment: @AmirHajdar, fee free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) (just click the checkmark to its left). I'll have a lookout to any new questions you may have :) (PS: [oXygen](http://oxygenxml.com), arguably the best, works on Mac, as does Eclipse)